# Best practice for similar repeated queries using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a couple simple queries and I'm not sure what the best practice is.

I've written them in 2 ways which produce the same result.  Which is preferred?  Or is there a third, better way?

More concise:

```
Fruit.where(id: NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS).update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: false)
Fruit.where.not(id: NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS).update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: true)
```

More verbose:

```
fruits = Fruit.all
not_prepackaged = fruits.where(id: NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS)
prepackaged = fruits - not_prepackaged
not_prepackaged.update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: false)
prepackaged.update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: true)
```

The purpose of the snippet is to do a onetime backfill.

Comment: Having a constant that contains database ids is a red flag as it implies that you are hardcoding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in a single statement/query, you can write it like this:

```rb
Fruit.update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled:
  Fruit.arel_table[:id].not_in(NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS)
)
```

If `NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS` is `[571, 572]`, then the statement would translate to the following SQL, which will update all of the records at once:

```sql
UPDATE "fruits" 
SET "prepackaged_raw_enabled" = "fruits"."id" NOT IN (571, 572)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good alternative!  I think its DRYer and more less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more context, your first example is easier to follow.
Assuming you want to touch every single record, it might improve clarity (although would be a little slower) if you backfill all records, then just the subset:

```
Fruit.update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: true)
Fruit.where(id: NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS).update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: false)
```

Or maybe it's safer for your setup to do it the other way around (although the double negative is not ideal):

```
Fruit.update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: false)
Fruit.where.not(id: NOT_PREPACKAGED_RAW_FRUIT_IDS).update_all(prepackaged_raw_enabled: true)
```

Comment: Why would it be safer?

Comment: @max I don't know which default is preferred, but maybe `false` is the preferred default value for that field. If so, it's a little bit safer to assign everything as the default first, then assign the non-default values. Mostly because another developer coming along will understand better about the default situation. I can also maybe envision some extreme situation where the constant doesn't cover everything it should have and needs updating, but maybe I'm just being paranoid there.

Comment: You're right, one of the motivations was to not use a double negative.  Thanks for your answer!